# How to set "Grid.Row" programmatically to a ui control?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am adding new textboxes dynamically and I need to add a new row doing so.
How do I associate a new textbox, `TextBox txt1 = new TextBox();` , to a Row Definition index?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the `Grid.Row` attached property by its [static setter method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms589026(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Grid.SetRow(txt1, rowIndex);
```

Answer (score 1):

For attached properties call `SetValue`

```
txt1.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, 3);
```

Or from the actual named grid's static `SetRow`

```
MyGrid.SetRow(txt1, 3);
```